# How to split the number for each row in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am actually working on to split the quantity number for each of the row.

Example :

Total Quantity for each container: 29

For some reason, the max limit for the 1st batch is 10, and the second batch is 69

I have tried to write the query like below, but it return wrongly.

```
select case when totalQ < 29.5 then Quantity else Quantity
end as Quantity, lotno, totalQ  from (
select quantity - 29.5 as totalQ,
* from TestB where id in (
select id from TestA where id =20))A
```

[image]

However, I am expecting something like below:

[image]

Could anyone please help me to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're looking for. Maybe we can see some more examples of INPUT and Expected Output.

Comment: If you write "case <condition> then <X> else <X> end", the result is always going to be <X>.

Comment: As I understand it, you have one row with a total quantity, and you need to break it into several rows that add up to that quantity, but no row has more than 29.  So a single row with total quantity of 70 becomes 3 rows with 29, 29, and 12.  Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: @daviddubious yes, thats what i am looking for, i think my query is wrong too, but i not sure how to fix it

Comment: @DavidDubois what a thoughtful way of determining what the OP needed! Nice!

Comment: @MuhammadAkmal https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic568498-338-1.aspx might be able to give you some inspiration using CTE recursion.

Comment: Thanks, zedfoxus.  Your link made it easier to find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
create table TestB ( BatchID varchar(10), TotalQuantity int )

insert into TestB ( BatchID, TotalQuantity ) values
( 'A', 70 ), ( 'B', 10 ), ( 'C', 69 ), ( 'D', 100 ),
( 'E',  0 ), ( 'F', 29 ), ( 'G', 58 ), ( 'H', 200 )

; with 
A as
  ( select BatchID, 
           case when TotalQuantity >= 29 then 29 else TotalQuantity end as Quantity,
           case when TotalQuantity >= 29 then TotalQuantity - 29 else 0 end as Remaining
    from TestB 

    union all

    select BatchID, 
           case when Remaining >= 29 then 29 else Remaining end as Quantity,
           case when Remaining >= 29 then Remaining - 29 else 0 end as Remaining
    from A
    where Remaining > 0 )

    select BatchID, 
           Quantity 
    from A 
    order by BatchID, 
             Quantity desc
    option ( MaxRecursion 1000 )
```

Comment: Nice answer, David.

Comment: Hey this is very nice answer :)

Comment: If you've found this answer helpful, please accept it.

Comment: @MuhammadAkmal there should be a check mark besides this answer. Click on that will mark this answer as accepted and will give closure to your question. To upvote the answer, click the arrow pointing up.

Answer (score 2):

David's answer is pretty nice. This is a longer answer using SQL Stored Procedure.

Example is here: http://rextester.com/VUQXVQ46335

**Stored Procedure**

```
create table test (batch varchar(20), quantity int);
insert into test values ('lot0', 29), ('lot1', 30), ('lot2', 28), ('lot3', 100);
go

create procedure CreateBatches (@BatchSize int)
as
begin

  -- declare variables and create a temporary table
  set nocount on
  declare @v_batch varchar(20), @v_quantity int
  create table #tempTest (batch varchar(20), quantity int)

  -- loop through all records
  declare testCursor cursor for select * from test
  open testCursor
  fetch next from testCursor into @v_batch, @v_quantity

  -- process each record
  while @@fetch_status = 0
  begin
      -- if quantity is larger than the bucket, insert the batch size in the table
      -- reduce the quantity and continue looping
      while @v_quantity > @BatchSize
      begin
        insert into #tempTest values (@v_batch, @BatchSize)
        set @v_quantity = @v_quantity - @BatchSize
      end

      -- store the quantity lower than the batch size in the table
      insert into #tempTest values (@v_batch, @v_quantity)
      fetch next from testCursor into @v_batch, @v_quantity
  end

  select * from #tempTest
  drop table #tempTest
  close testCursor
  deallocate testCursor
  set nocount off

end;
go
```

**Result**

```
exec CreateBatches 32;

#   batch   quantity
1   lot0    29
2   lot1    30
3   lot2    28
4   lot3    32
5   lot3    32
6   lot3    32
7   lot3    4
```

**Another run**

```
exec CreateBatches 29;

#   batch   quantity
1   lot0    29
2   lot1    29
3   lot1    1
4   lot2    28
5   lot3    29
6   lot3    29
7   lot3    29
8   lot3    13
```

This method gives you a bit of flexibility and a little more understanding of how the batching system works. It is possible that the Stored Procedure will be slow when processing a large amount of data.

**Comparison**

I did a comparison of David's recursive CTE and Stored Procedure. I created 3031 lots/batches/records starting with 500 quantity for lot 1, 600 for lot 2...303500 for lot 3031.

**Results**

Results are in seconds. Dash means the query was aborted after 12s.

```
Batch size  CTE    SP
----------  -----  -----
300000      1.46s  1.66s
200000      1.61s  1.88s
100000      2.27s  2.47s
 50000      5.00s  5.41s
 25000      7.71s  8.05s
 12500      -      -
```

These are just crude results testing on rextester. You can see that stored procedure is slower than CTE.

Answer (score 0):

use self join and union

```
select t.batch,t.quantity from t join t t1 on t.batch=t1.batch
union 
select t.batch,t.totalQ from t join t t1 on t.batch=t1.batch
```

Comment: It sounds that easy, but it's not. This is a bucket problem, it appears. If Lot1 had 32 items, OP wants to have 2 records - Lot1 with 29 items and Lot2 with 3 items. If Lot2 had 60 items, OP wants to have 3 records - first with 29 items, second with 29 items and third with 2 items. That's my understanding based on David and Mohammad's commentary.